# Unable to display tabs of DataTable inline in Jupyter notebook

Tags: tabs, datatables, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, slickgrid

I am trying to display multiple dataframe in tabs using Bokeh. My code works when I save my file as html, but it fail to display inline in the Jupyter notebook. 
Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter,
TableColumn, Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)

source = ColumnDataSource(train.head())
columns = [TableColumn(field=col, title=col) for col in train.columns.tolist()]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)
tab1 = Panel(child=data_table, title="Train")

source = ColumnDataSource(prop.head())
columns = [TableColumn(field=col, title=col) for col in prop.columns.tolist()]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=len(columns)*100, height=280)
tab2 = Panel(child=data_table, title="Properties")

tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])
show(tabs)
```

Here is the error messege:

```
Javascript error adding output!
Error: SlickGrid's 'enableColumnReorder = true' option requires jquery-ui.sortable module to be loaded
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Here is my set up:

```
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.0.1
jupyter-console==5.1.0
jupyter-core==4.3.0
bokeh==0.12.7
```

Can someone point me a direction as what I can do to fix this?
Thanks in advance!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a SlickGrid error message. Like it says, jQueryUI.sortable is a dependency for SlickGrid.
I normally include the full build of jQueryUI in the page, along with jQuery itself, like:

```
<script src="../lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

(or you could use the jQuery CDN).
You can also include a cut down version of jQueryUI that just includes *sortable* (there are known conflicts between jQueryUI and other frameworks, for example Bootstrap).

If slickgrid is part of the page, you should already have this stuff set up though.
I have no clue about Bokeh.